# Multiple environments in single hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

Is it possible to set up multiple environments (prod,pre-prod,dev etc..) in a single hadoop cluster? The idea is to have a single cluster and have separate partition for each environment and restrict access to these directories to only required users (depends on environments). Also to restrict job submission enable resource pooling with queues.

Is this viable option? what are the possible issues with this set up?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in principle. As a minimum, you will need to introduce Kerberos security to control access to your cluster resources. Also consider using either Ranger or Sentry to manage your access roles, because access management across all services will be near impossible otherwise. Note that all these tools still have some rough edges.

Comment: "Rough edges" is an understatement; Kerberos is a nightmare, is has been implemented (or worked around) in at least 5 different ways e.g. HDFS/YARN, HBase, WebHDFS, GUIs, Oozie...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you state that Kerberos is mandatory - versus just using a different set of "users" for each environment and setting up ACLs for HDFS, YARN queues, etc *(which you have to do anyway)*?

Comment: Because without Kerberos, you don't have any security. Anybody could pretend to be any user they want to impersonate.

Comment: Right, but if "NP1987" wants a single cluster for Prod and Dev, do you really think he/she cares about *security*?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Now that's another question that should be taken outside this forum. This is moving from Hadoop security to a much broader architecture consideration.

Comment: Yes; we are planning to have kerberos as well roles created using sentry.